Pass environment variables to tests but not the cargo binary
For example, I want to run the test with MALLOC_CONF="prof:true,prof_active:false", so I could just do
LD_PRELOAD=jemalloc-5.2.1/lib/libjemalloc.so.2 MALLOC_CONF="prof:true,prof_active:false" LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib cargo test --package my_package --test my_mod test_jemalloc_prof

However, because cargo test itself does't support jemalloc heap profiling, so we could get error messages like the following while compiling
<jemalloc>: Invalid conf pair: prof_active:false
<jemalloc>: Invalid conf pair: prof:true

My question is how to avoid this, and set MALLOC_CONF only in running stage.

I am not sure what you want to do, but if you want to set env variables during tests you can use temp-env crate.

Let me understand: are you trying to set an environment variable for the tests, but not for the cargo binary itself?

@ChayimFriedman Yes. Have I asked a question that is not so easy to comprehend? Could you please help me simplify it?

I've edited the title. Hopefully it should be clearer now.

This was considered for Cargo but rejected. As a workaround, you can run the test binary directly. Cargo output its path when running cargo test. For example:
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/my_test-c11821121b337a71)

